# Execute task with different inputs for different hosts

Tags: python, configuration, ansible, yaml, jinja2

Suppose I have a task like this:

```
- name: install python modules
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - requests
```

And I want to execute that one on all the hosts in play, but with different `with_items` depending on the host. is that possible. I was unable to locate anything relevant on the web.

My goal is to configure 4 similar, but slightly different boxes. All the tasks are the same, but inputs slightly differ. I don't want to have 4 consequtive plays. I want 1 parallel play.

Comment: You want to read about [host variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#host-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds pretty basic: define variable containing a list of package names separately for each host in either:

- [the inventory file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#host-variables),
- or preferably in [`hosts_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data).

Comment: Example for what? What is your particular case? You need to write a few text files with variable assignment,

Comment: I’m really clueless what is your concern. You can specify `with_items: “{{ variable }}”`, you know that?

Comment: so basically those are just vars files but placed in a specific directory. and if i want to do `with_items` and use host variable I have to call them the same name for different hosts, and they will expand into different values? the problem is I dont have these hosts when I start the playbook (playbook creates those). will they be able to get these vars?

Comment: Yes, the values will differ per host they were defined for. So what is in the inventory file? If you use an in-memory one, you can specify the values too http:/bdocs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/add_host_module.html but then I don’t understand how you decide what should be installed where.

Comment: ok, I'll take a look at this later, I'm not at my work yet ;) and I wasn't looking at this yesterday, because my work day ended ;) I'll get back to you today and mark this

Answer (score 0):

I've went a slightly different route, as I'm trying to keep things dynamic:

I have an `add_host` task, which iterates over a list:

```
- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ item }}"
    var: "{{ var[item] }}"
  with_items: "{{ myList }}"
```

This way I can have a separate vars file where I keep configurations of my hosts defined as variables:

```
var:
  host1:
    - xxx
    - yyy
  host2:
    - zzz
    - vvv
```